# Не получается асинхронный запрос в webforms

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net, asp.net-webforms, веб-служба

Здравствуйте, подскажите, почему не выполняется асинхронный запрос. Вместо этого обновляется вся страница. Вот кусок кода страницы:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function check() {

        var text = $get("TextBoxlogin").value;
        TestsApps.CheckLogin(text, onComplete)
    }

    function onComplete(result) {
        if (result) {
            $get("Labelcheck").innerHTML = "Login was used ";

        }
        else {
            $get("Labelcheck").innerHTML = "Login is free ";

        }
    }

       </script>
  </head>
   <body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:ScriptManager runat="server">
                    <Services>
            <asp:ServiceReference Path="~/WebService1.asmx" />
        </Services>
    </asp:ScriptManager>

          Registration<table class="auto-style1">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Login"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxlogin" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:Button ID="Buttoncheck" runat="server"  BorderColor="#6600FF" OnClientClick="check()"   Text="check" ClientIDMode="Static" />


                <asp:Label ID="Labelcheck" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" ControlToValidate="TextBoxlogin" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Это поле не может быть пустым!"
        ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

Веб-служба:

```
public class WebService1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod(true)]
    public bool CheckLogin(string login)
    {
        string tmp = " ";
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename='C:\Users\Оксана\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\TestsApps\TestsApps\App_Data\Database.mdf';Integrated Security=True");
        connection.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = string.Format("SELECT Login FROM Profile WHERE Login =          {0}", login);
            using (SqlDataReader r = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (r.Read())
                {

                    tmp+=(string)r[1];

                }

            }
        }
        connection.Close();
        if (String.Compare(tmp, login) == 0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;

    }
     }
       }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого необходимо, чтобы код в `OnClientClick` возвращал `false`:

```
<asp:Button ID="Buttoncheck" runat="server" BorderColor="#6600FF"
    OnClientClick="check(); return false;" Text="check" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

Comment: Все равно перегружается страница и не срабатывает клиентский код

Comment: @Nameless над классом WebService1 стоит атрибут ScriptService? На странице в скрипте вызывайте сервис через `<Namespace>.WebService1.CheckLogin(text, onComplete);`, вместо `<Namespace>` подставьте пространство имен, где находится класс WebService1 (хотя в принципе пространство имен не должно быть обязательным)

Comment: Спасибо, помогло